# changing the text on a button on click

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I am working with **Angular 7** and I want to **change text on button every time It click either it should be login or logout**

I am putting my code below:

ts file:

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  text: any;

  constructor() {
    this.loadDataFromApi();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
      if (this.token == null) {
        this.text == 'login';
        alert(this.text);

      } else if (this.token) {
         this.token == 'logout';
         alert(this.text);
      }
   }

}
```

An alert **undefined** is coming

html file:

```
 <button type="button"> {{text}}</button>
```

Comment: token is declared in ts file

Comment: It seems like missing the token variable.

Comment: this.token == 'logout'; is typo it should be   this.token = 'logout';

Comment: can you try out solution

Comment: why double (==) equal for assign?

Comment: this.token i dont see this defined in you component.ts file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a Comparison Operator(`==`) instead of the assignment operator(`=`). Change that and it should work just fine. Something like this:

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  text: any;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadDataFromApi();
    if (this.token) {
      this.text = 'logout';
      alert(this.text);
    } else {
      this.text = 'login';
      alert(this.text);
    }
  }
}
```

**PS:** `this.loadDataFromApi` is most probably `async` in nature and the code below this call would get executed without waiting for it, thus leading to unexpected behavior. So in most of the cases, you would get `login` in the alert.

Comment: I tryied with your sollution but still I am getting undefined 

  ngOnInit() {

    if(this.token == null){
      alert(1);

      this.text = 'login';
      alert(this.text);

    } else if (this.token){
       alert('2');
      this.token = 'logout';
      alert(this.text);

    }
}

Comment: @TestingAnurag, check the updated answer. You had `this.token` instead of `this.text`  in your `else` condition.

Answer (score 2):

You should use assignment `=` operator instead of comparison `==` operator

```
this.text ='login';

 export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

    text: any;
    constructor( );

        this.loadDataFromApi();
      }
    ngOnInit() {

        if(this.token == null){
          this.text ='login';
          alert(this.text);

        } else if (this.token){
          this.token = 'logout';
          alert(this.text);

        }
    }
```

Comment: I tryied with your sollution but still I am getting undefined 

  ngOnInit() {

    if(this.token == null){
      alert(1);

      this.text = 'login';
      alert(this.text);

    } else if (this.token){
       alert('2');
      this.token = 'logout';
      alert(this.text);

    }
}

Answer (score 2):

try , instead of `this.token == null` try `!this.token`(this checks for undefiend as well as null and it recommended way )

```
   if(!this.token){
      this.text = 'login';
      alert(this.text);

    } else if (this.token){
      this.text== 'logout';
      alert(this.text);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

After the `else` you are modifying `this.token` and not `this.text`.

Moreover, You should use `=`, not `==` to assign `this.text`. Change your code like that:

```
ngOnInit() {
    if (this.token === null) {
        this.text = 'login';
        alert(this.text);

    } else if (this.token) {
        this.text = 'logout';
        alert(this.text);
    }
}
```

**PS**: Where is defined your `token` variable? I can't see it in your `.ts` file.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are checking if **auth token** is there then you are making the text as logout and token is not their show login.

In your case seems this.token is undefined as default

that's why in the alert it's showing undefined.

Two conditions will not work

it should be like

```
if (this.token) {//The user is logged in so log out should show.
    this.text = 'logout';
    alert(this.text);

  } else {//The user is logged out  in so login should show
     this.token == 'logout';
     alert(this.text);
  }
```

Please check first the value of this.token, whether the value is set or not.